# Find last child of specific element

Tags: javascript, css, dom

The question is really confusing but I'll try to explain here.

In CSS I know you can say "if this DIV has x and y and z inside it in any way" then apply this style.  Like

```
div.class id class { style }
```

I was wondering how I would go about doing this in Javascript for detecting the last child.

Such as getting if

```
div div:nth-child(2) span a
```

is the last child of a certain div in Javascript.

I hope this is not too confusing because it sure looks confusing to me...  If you need clarification please ask.

Comment: Use jQuery if you can. You can get CSS selectors to use in jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

I am going to post an answer despite the previous one, because I refuse to use (and intend to try to convince others to stop using) w3schools.

So, a much better resource: [MDN - lastChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.lastChild)

And inline:

```
var tr = document.getElementById("row1");
var corner_td = tr.lastChild;
```

As a bonus, and in sync with the above [w3fools](http://www.w3fools.com/)

Comment: No "c", it's w3schools/fools

Answer (score 1):

> 1) Try this by jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var list = $("#containerId").children();
        var lastElement = list[list.length - 1];
    });

OR

2) pure javascript

 var list = document.getElementById('containerId').children;
        var lastElement = list[list.length - 1];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are loking for [lastChild](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_lastchild.asp) property